# a function pointer as a function paramter - should one const it?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, function-parameter

If I write something as follows:

```
int f(char x, const int (*g) (const char x)) {
    return g(x);
}
```

does the first `const` say effectively what I think it says, namely basically that the programmer can't change the **code** of the function g? So basically, it is a good practice to put those `const`s when passing a function pointer as a parameter?

Comment: The rule of thumb here is to _never_ use function pointers without a typedef. None of the `const` in your example are good practice and neither is a parameter of type `int (*const g)(char)`. None of it is related to _const correctness_.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, thanks, I understand that now after some more reading (about the consts being completely not useful). Anyway, you mean I should typedef int (*function_parameter) (char x); and then use that in the function parameter?

Comment: I prefer not to hide any pointer inside the typedef: ` typedef int func_t (char x);` ... `int f(char x, func_t* func);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `const` declares the returned `int` to be immutable - but that will not matter since the receiver will copy it into a non-`const` `int` if that's wanted - which is exactly what your `f()` function does. It calls `g()` which is declared to return a `const int` but `f()` returns an `int`. The first `const` will just be ignored.

It does not have to do with changing the code of `g()`. That's not allowed under any circumstances.

If you want to make it clear that the function pointer will not be made to point at another function inside `f`:

```c
int f(char x, int (*const g) (const char x))
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, I see. The first const refers to the int, not to the function pointer parameter; so if I got you right, function pointers can't be const'ed because anyway we can't modify their dereferencing...

Comment: @Sasha Almost correct. You can make the pointer itself `const` so that it can't be changed inside the function. I added such a declaration to the answer.

Comment: Note that the second const is ignored as well when inferring the type of parameter `g`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks. Although, it seems quite useless in practice to do this const, no? The "API user" looking at the declaration should not really care if I change the pointer in the function for my convenience for some reason.